# Is it possible to return a deleted column?

Tags: sql

To delete a column in table I am using `DROP COLUMN` command from `Alter Table`. After I did it, is it possible (somehow) to return the deleted column?

Comment: Erm, no. That's kinda what DROP COLUMN does...

Comment: well no... you deleted it...

Comment: no, the column does not exist

Comment: Yup. There is something call backup. You have it,dont you?

Comment: Is there any alternative command to delete a column and return it?

Comment: Depends on the DBMS in use. In Oracle you could do (if configured) a `flashback table`

Comment: As @GoatCO stated, you can re-add the column using ADD COLUMN with ALTER TABLE, but it won't restore the data you lost when you deleted the column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can re-add the column easily, syntax depends on the database.  As far as recovering the values of the deleted column, you'd need a backup for that if it's not preserved in an open transaction.

Comment: or you can run a select on the values you want before deleting them. but backups would be a better idea.